Calculating BLEU score between two sumamries in python
prediction = "I am ABC. I have completed my bachelor's degree in computer application at XYZ University and I am currently pursuing my master's degree in computer application through distance education."


reference = "I'm ABC. I have finished my four-year certification in PC application at XYZ and I'm currently pursuing my graduate degree in PC application through distance training."

from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu

# Tokenize the sentences
prediction_tokens = prediction.split()
reference_tokens = reference.split()

# Calculate BLEU score
bleu_score = sentence_bleu([reference_tokens], prediction_tokens)

# Print the BLEU score
print(f"BLEU score: {bleu_score:.4f}")

I am getting BLEU score as 0. I think I am making mistake somwhere. But not sure where.

you haven't defined the variables prediction and reference in your code

you forgot to add the information that you get when running the code. Please update your question to add this information, since it's relevant "The hypothesis contains 0 counts of 4-gram overlaps.
Therefore the BLEU score evaluates to 0, independently of
how many N-gram overlaps of lower order it contains.
Consider using lower n-gram order or use SmoothingFunction()
warnings.warn(_msg)
BLEU score: 0.0000"
