Calculating BLEU score between candidate and reference sentences in python
I am calculating BLEU score between 2 sentences which seem very similar to me but I am getting BLEU score as very low. Is it supposed to happen?
prediction = "I am ABC."
reference = "I'm ABC."

from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu, corpus_bleu
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import SmoothingFunction
# Tokenize the sentences
prediction_tokens = prediction.split()
reference_tokens = reference.split()
   
# Calculate BLEU score
bleu_score = sentence_bleu([reference_tokens], prediction_tokens, smoothing_function=SmoothingFunction().method4)

# Print the BLEU score
print(f"BLEU score: {bleu_score:.4f}")

Output is 0.0725


You already asked the same question two times previously, that is not allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78299375/calculating-bleu-score-between-two-sumamries-in-python

You can always edit your own questions, there is no need to create duplicates, because this is not a Forum

Could you mark the answer as correct if it is indeed the case?

Yes, for two reasons:

Tokenization: "I am" vs. "I'm" lead to different tokenizations. BLEU scores are very sensitive to tokens. The different tokenization should lead to substantial impact.
Short sentences: BLEU are notoriously unreliable for very short texts. The score will be disproportionately influenced by small differences if there isn't much text to begin with because there is a Brevity Penalty set in place to discourage the model from outputting fewer words and get a high score. Please take a look at the "Brevity Penalty" section in the following article.

Hope you found the answer you are looking for .

In that case so when my
prediction = "I am ABC."
reference = "I am ABC."
The BLEU score should be 1, right? But I am getting it as 0.5757, even though all the tokens are similar. What is the probable reason for it?

No, there is a Brevity Penalty set in place to discourage the model from outputting fewer words and get a high score. Please take a look at the "Brevity Penalty" section in the following article https://towardsdatascience.com/foundations-of-nlp-explained-bleu-score-and-wer-metrics-1a5ba06d812b. Make the sentence 50 characters longer and run the code again to better understand the phenomenon. Hope it helps you .
